# How do i change the UI of a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I like to change the UI of a JComboBox from the default metal look to some custom UI, see attached image.

[image: Sample]

I have tried changing all the UIDefaults for the JComboBox but to no success.

How does one achieve this?

jdk1.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write your own ComboBoxUI class. 
I suggest to look at either Synth or Nimbus Look and Feel to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change arrow image , and in style change background for this JComboBox !

Answer (score 0):

use WindowsLookAndFeel;

this works if and only if you are running your application in winows;

in your main you can do this before creating any UI:

```
try{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}catch(Exception ignore){
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the app will be run in the wild, and may be launched on any OS