# How can I change the UI of all components of a certain type?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, uimanager

How can I set the UI for all components in my application without having to reference each one of them using `component.setUI(...);` ?

For example, I have several custom `JScrollbars` throughout my program, 
and when you switch to another theme I have to reset all the UI's like this: `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new CustomScrollBarUI());`

I would prefer to not have to look up each one seperately when changing themes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (or at least, same answer as) [How do i change the UI of a JComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026559/how-do-i-change-the-ui-of-a-jcombobox).

Comment: See also [Smoother scrolling in a JScrollPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170291/smoother-scrolling-in-a-jscrollpane)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `UIDefaults` early in your program:

```
UIDefaults uiDefaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
uiDefaults.put("ScrollBarUI", new CustomScrollBarUI());
```

See also [*Changing UI Default Settings in Java: The UIDefaults Class*](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29991).